# IP address in Tcptrace output

Tags: output, tcptrace

I am using a command of TCPTRACE to get flow information from a PCAP file generated by tcpdump, so here is the command I use:

> tcptrace -l -u -n -W PCAPlog

but my problem is that I get this addresses: **fe80::dd84:b89d:015c:c42a** (for example) instead of IP address in some lines, but I want only IP addresses in my output, how can I change that??

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, but fe80::dd84:b89d:015c:c42a is a legitimate **IPv6** address. It is a shorten form of fe80:0000:0000:0000:dd84:b89d:015c:c42a.

The conventions and rules of representing IPv6 addresses is [refered here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-4).